# How to use own custom imagery instead of google map in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have developed an app in android where I am using Google Map for capturing location. I have a large satellite image ( greater than 500 mb ), this image is geo-coded. We need to display this as one of the layers in the map like google map has a choice for satellite imagery. How can it be done.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "imaginery"? Do want to change the map tiles or the marker icons?

Comment: yes i want to use a custom map image instead of google map.

Answer (score 0):

To add custom imaginery to your map you can use `TileOverlay`:

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) of `TileOverlay`

> A TileOverlay defines a set of images that are added on top of the base map tiles. You can also use tile overlays to add extra features to the map by providing transparent tile images. You need to provide the tiles for each zoom level that you want to support. If you have enough tiles at multiple zoom levels, you can supplement Google's map data for the entire map.
>
> Tile overlays are useful when you want to add extensive imagery to the map, typically covering large geographical areas. In contrast, ground overlays are useful when you wish to fix a single image at one area on the map.

To use `TileOverlay` you need to implement a `TileProvider` that returns the correct `Tile` object for each tile requested by the map.

Take into account that your data (your images) need to be georeferenced to return the correct tiles to be drawn on the map.

Once your data is displayed you may want to do `map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);` to stop asking for Google tiles.

**Update based on the comments:**

As you say that you want to automate the tiling for different image formats, you will need to implement a `TileProvider` for each of the image formats that you want to be able to load.

To return the correct `Tile` you will need to transform between the tile x, y, and zoom (the parameters of the `public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom)` function of the `TileProvider` interface) and the coordinates (and pixels) of you georeferenced image. You can take a look at http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/ to learn more about the tiling system.

Also, if the image's srid not WGS84 you will need to geotransform your data.

Take into account that if your image is big and you are showing a large area you may find OutOfMemory errors, and you may want to take a look at [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to load a scaled down version of your image to be returned as the tile.

Comment: I just have only one georeferenced image for a large area but I dont have set of tiles for each zoom level

Comment: What format is your image, what size and what srid is it in?

Comment: I need to automate the tiling in the app itself i.e user will have the option to select image from server or local memory and the app will do the tiling and then load the image. Right now the image I have is georeferenced JPEG file but it can be in any format which support georeference.

Comment: I want my app to cut the image into various tiles for various zoom levels. It will be like when I browse the image or download the image it will render and cut the image into tiles and notify the user that the image is ready to view.