# Graphic below specific area in some Android Map API

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I'm looking form maps API that would allow me to put pattern in some form (maybe graphic) below forest area, to have something like this (image below) and not only plain colour. Later on I would need to put such images on different areas and roads, also ability to put some 3D building on map would be great.

I found only ways of adding 3D objects and chagning area colours. Maybe I'm using bad words but only results on stackverflow and google were for custom background in markes.

Can you recommend some map API? (If you have some open-source project where I can see how its done it would be awesome. Thank you for your help.

[image: Maps with graphic below forest]

Comment: You don't need any API for this, just download the specific [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) you are interested in. This is exactly the same your browser does, take a look at the images and their URLs. To get the tile names for a certain location see [Slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames), specifically "Lon./lat. to tile numbers".

Comment: Yes, but this does not allow me to change background of specific area to my custom texture.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415962/how-to-use-own-custom-imagery-instead-of-google-map-in-android-app/33417752#33417752

Comment: Unfortunately not what I need here. In given solution you have your own tiles, so I would need to prepare them before displaying on maps, for overlaying every forest and other areas I could just copy whole world tiles and make my own tile server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution I decided to use is to render vector tiles on your own. There are two good services to obtain tiles:

1. [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) tiles in MVT format - any zoom, to get tile just use link https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt?access_token={access_token}
2. [MapTiler Tilehosting](https://www.tilehosting.com/) tiles in PBF format - zoom max 14, PBF format is basically same as Mapbox MVT (same parsers might be used), to get tile just use link https://free.tilehosting.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?key={access_token}

When decoding thies some Polygons might not parse properly, here is answer for that question:
[Mapbox vector tile MVT is missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291092/mapbox-vector-tile-mvt-is-missing-data)

Rendered tiles can be used with google API by [TileOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay), this gives all Google API features and it is easy to use (mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE); to disable all google map labels). Downside is of course tile rendering that needs to be done on your won, but for me this is positive, because I have full control on what is displayed (I use OpenGL ES, I recommend EGL14, [off-screen rendering here](https://mkonrad.net/2014/12/08/android-off-screen-rendering-using-egl-pixelbuffers.html)).

Comment: Yes, I had to do some coding but it was ok :)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot o research I found the solution. It is to use [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) with it's vector tiles.

1. proiblem - area overlay:

Using [mapbox styles](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/) you can use **background-pattern**,
**fill-pattern**, **line-pattern**, **fill-extrusion-pattern**, or **icon-image** properties to overlay specific area type, so you can have even SSJ Blue Songo face covering whole forests :D. Vector tiles same as google API can be also colored as you like.

2. problem - 3D objects

3D objects like buildings can be placed in desired position, I even found some screanshots with mapbox and car placed on map.

Additionally it seams that when using Vector tiles you can use isometric view. Not yest tested, but form [this tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/#configure-your-mapview) it looks like it is possible. For all that hate paying for map services I found that you can host your own tile server and it will works as long as you provide tiles that are compatible with their tile specification.