# Mapbox vector tile MVT is missing data

Tags: mapbox

I'm trying to make my own renderer for Mapbox MVT vector tiles, but I have hit the obstacle and couldn't find the answer. My problem is that MVT tile downloaded form Mapbox server contains all roads, but only a few bulding numbers (should be much more for given area) and no land types (grean area on map) and buildings.

Anyone had same problem or know the answer?

link I use to download tile is:
https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2,mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7/18/143415/87627.mvt?access_token={access_token}

Below raster tile for the same area:

[image: Raster tile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in decoding MVT tiles (using [mapbox-vector-tile-java](https://github.com/wdtinc/mapbox-vector-tile-java)), to parse it properly **MvtReader.RING_CLASSIFIER_V1** needs to be used:

```
final JtsMvt result = MvtReader.loadMvt(f, new GeometryFactory(), new TagKeyValueMapConverter(), MvtReader.RING_CLASSIFIER_V1);
```

Resolved thanks to [boldtrn commit on mapsforge/vtm](https://github.com/mapsforge/vtm/pull/481/commits/a5a3461bebf123547db365880c13d20c1737b7ae)